# TFS Build is failing while running Moles

Tags: sharepoint-2010, msbuild, moles, pex-and-moles

My TFS 2010 Build is failing due to Moles framework. Its unable to generate sharepoint.moles assembly. Currently I am having Visual studio premium installed and Moles 64 bit on the Build server. Please note that this is a sharepoint 2010 project so manually sharepoint.dll are copied to the Build server. My question is  do we need to any Sharepoint or Foundation 2010 installed on the Build server. Also what whether Visual studio 2010 premium will support the Moles .

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure the dependencies of to SharePoint.DLL are there. Install de build server the same as you Dev machine will enable you to build like on you Dev machine. Moles it self is a separate install on you build server.